# How to find sets of polynomially bounded numbers whose subset sums are different?

Tags: asymptotics, sets, polynomials, subset-sum, upper-bound

Let $n$ be any positibe integer and set $N=\{1,\dots,n\}$. Now select two arbitrary but different subsets of $N$, say $S$ and $S'$. We are interested in finding a function $\pi(A)=\sum_{i\in A}a_i$ such that we always have $\pi(S) \ne \pi(S')$. For example, we can define $a_i = 2^i$. This function satisfies the property because for each $A \subseteq N$, $\pi(A)$ uniquely represents an integer written in base 2. However, in this function $a_i$ is bounded above by $\mathcal{O}(2^n)$. I am looking for a function such that $|a_i|$ and $\frac{1}{|a_i|}$ are bounded above by a polynomial. As an example that does not satisfy this last condition we can consider $a_i = 2^{i-n}$. It would be great to know different functions that satisfy this property. I will try to proof the uniqueness myself (if it is not so difficult!), so please let me know if you are aware of such functions.

Comment: You can choose $n$ random numbers between $0$ and $1$, and almost surely all sums will be different. If you want an explicit example, you can take $a_i = \pi^i/\lceil \pi^i \rceil$.

Comment: I'm not writing any answer, you can go ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many functions that satisfy your condition. Here are a few.

1. $a_i=1+c^{-i}$, for some constant $c\ge 2$.
2. $a_i= 1+b_i/p_i$, where $p_i$ is the $i^{th}$ prime number and $b_i$ is any integer between 1 and $p_i-1$.
3. $a_i =1+\alpha^i/\lceil\alpha^i\rceil$, for any positive transdental number $\alpha$. For example, you can take $\alpha = \pi$ or $\alpha=e$ or $\alpha=0.110001000000000000000001\cdots$, an Liouville number. (Yuval's method)
4. $a_i=c_1b_i+c_0$, where $b_i>0$ is such a function and $c_1, c_0$ are positive constant.
5. One can choose random numbers between a positive constant $c_0$ and 1, which should satisfy the requirement with probability one. The issue then is how to select/implement a random number generator and detect the outliers, which may or may not be trivial. (Yuval's method)

For the first three methods, the constant 1 can be replaced by some kind of polynomial of $n$. For example, a nonzero polynomial of $n$ with nonnegative integer coefficients.

These functions should get you going. If you find more ways, you can update this answer.